# Getting file name and file directory in PHP application by selecting file

Tags: php, file, browser

I'm currently making a PHP application, where I want to insert data from a excel sheet in a MySQL database. I've done that so far, but the problem now is, that the excel file needs to be in the root directory. What I'm looking for is a button where I can browse the file, and from which i get the name and the directory. Any suggestions?

currently I just use `$fileName="gefertigt.xlsx";`

I tried it with JavaScript (from [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) tutorial), but since I'm a beginner it's to difficult for me.

Comment: i guess the excel file should be uploaded by the user? please post yout js code

Comment: The excel file should be selected by the user in windows browser

Comment: and what is your javascript code you tried so far? note that PHP is executed serverside while JS is executed on the client

Comment: I tried the second tutorial from the link in my description

Comment: we need to see YOUR sources, because it is not working at your place ;)

Comment: which sources do you mean?

Comment: did you not try anything to code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a good solution for my problem, which is quiet easier than I thought. Instead of getting the directory of the file, I uploaded the file to a folder called "uploads" in my root directory. Since i knew that the file(which will always be an .xlsx file) will always be the same, but always with new content, it replaces the current file in the folder uploads with the upladed file.

code in html:

```
<form action="dbconnection.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Datei auswaehlen
        <input type="file" name="dateiHochladen" id="dateiHochladen">
        <input type="submit" value="Hochladen" name="submit">
    </form>
```

code in php:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["dateiHochladen"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dateiHochladen"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["dateiHochladen"]["name"]). " wurde hochgeladen.";
        } else {
            echo "Fehler beim hochladen.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP filesystem has two functions, `basename()` and `dirname()`, which give the filename and directory, respectively. Thus your answer is:

```
function get_name_and_directory($file) {
    return array(
        'name' => basename($file),
        'directory' => dirname($file)
    );
}
```